# Изменить расположение и наличие инструментов на ToolBar в Android studio

Tags: android-studio, toolbar

Переустановил Android Studio.

Расположение и разнообразие инструментов было примерно это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После переустановки - это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Давно не пользовался Android Studio. Может это нововведение такое? Но как вернуть расположение и наличие инструментов так, как это было в предыдущих версиях? Где эти настройки? Никак не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать как было, нужно сделать активным, собственно, тулбар -
 установить отметку *View -> Toolbar*:

[image: scrn]